# How to access HttpContext.Session from NextJs

Tags: asp.net-core, axios, next.js

Am using Nextjs for front end and Asp.Net core as a backend (API). I use JWT authentication to access the endpoints from Next Js using axios. Am also setting sessions on the backend to store user data. The problem is that HttpContext.Session is always null. The following is a sample of code I use:

```
axios.post(`https://localhost:44301/Home/GetValues`, { },       

    {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'

        },
        withCredentials: true
    }
)
    .then(res => {
        console.log("Values", res.data);          

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

With Postman am able to access the HttpContext.Session. That means the Nextjs is not sending session cookies set by the Asp.net core.

Comment: Might be a CORS-related issue due to wildcarding, I won't post this as an answer just yet due to it being just an attempt, but try and your API Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:44301 and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Comment: @Nemoverflow I have tried setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin, still HttpContext.Session is null.

Comment: Where is that `axios` request being made from in your Next.js app: client-side or server-side (`getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps`)?

Comment: @juliomalves am neither using getStaticProps nor getServerSideProps. I have a button on UI which has onClick function. Inside the function am using axios to call the backend api. Bear in mind that am using a child component not NextJs page to call the api.

Comment: My requirement is not pre-render the page but basic CRUD operations to the API. That's why using getStaticProps or getServerSideProps is not an option.